# How to extact the digits using regex in oracle from its 10th to 18th occurence from a string?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

The String can be in any format few example are shown below

- 123456789, 999999999, 123456789 (Output 999999999)
- 123456789 ---987654321---987654321---999999999 (Output 987654321)
- 753812569/999999999/965421678/212123512 (Output 999999999)
- bcr987654321 |bcr 123456789 (Output 123456789)

Answer (score 0):

Remove all non-digit characters then take the 9-character substring starting from the 10th character:

```
SELECT SUBSTR( REGEXP_REPLACE( value, '\D' ), 10, 9 )
FROM   table_name;
```

So, for your test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value ) AS
SELECT '123456789, 999999999, 123456789' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '123456789 ---987654321---987654321---999999999' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '753812569/999999999/965421678/212123512' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'bcr987654321 |bcr 123456789' FROM DUAL
```

This outputs:

> ```
> | SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE(VALUE,'\D'),10,9) |
> | :-------------------------------------- |
> | 999999999                               |
> | 987654321                               |
> | 999999999                               |
> | 123456789                               |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1905096fa72e679839008d6459518f72)*